# find IDs of databases with error during upgrade

Tags: text-processing, logs

I have a log file of errors captured in my database, the file contains a list of the records that had errors and were not updated. The record names are 10 digits and start with a strA:

```
Error: could not save changes to record strA5903427123
Error: could not save changes to record strB4403298440
Error: could not save changes to record strC5903427342
Error: could not save changes to record strD4403298988
Error: could not save changes to record strE5903427298
Error: could not save changes to record strF4403298232
Error: could not save changes to record strG5903427455
Error: could not save changes to record strH4403298223
```

I want to extract the list of ten digits and A and remove "Error: could not save changes to record str", how can I do it in bash, this is a very long list and I have many files like this one everyone for the database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you want?

```
sed -e 's/^.*str//' test.in
```

Comment: @Gabi ... you need to edit the question. `start with a strA` is mentioned instead of `start with a str`

Answer (score 1):

You can do it in `awk` as follows:

```
awk '{print $8}' file | tr -d "str"

A5903427123
B4403298440
C5903427342
D4403298988
E5903427298
F4403298232
G5903427455
H4403298223
```

Answer (score 1):

using `grep` to list the 10 digit ID that starts with `A`

```
grep -Eo "A[0-9]{10}" file
```

output

```
A5903427123
```

To list the 10 digit ID that starts with any uppercase alpha.

```
grep -Eo "[A-Z][0-9]{10}"  file

A5903427123
C5903427342
D4403298988
E5903427298
F4403298232
G5903427455
H4403298223
```